# Painless (Elasticsearch) convert any type of value to integer

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am converting an Elasticsearch script from Groovy to Painless.
The script accepts a parameter, which can be either an integer or a string convertible to an integer (i.e. could be either **123** or **"123"**).

In Groovy, doing **my_val.toLong()** converted both just fine, but that method is not available in Painless.

Is there any alternative syntax that would do the same in Painless?

I tried explicit casting with **(long) my_var**, but I get **java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number**

In short, I want to do the following in Painless and to get **true** as a result:

```
GET _search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "test": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "groovy",
        "params": {
          "my_val1": "123",
          "my_val2": 123
        },
        "source": """
        my_val1.toLong() == my_val2.toLong()
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since I can see this question is still getting some interest, in the end the best way I could find to do this is:

```
Long.parseLong(params.my_val1.toString()) == Long.parseLong(params.my_val2.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was use integer field `Math.abs(doc['age'] - 30)` directly.

After change it to `Math.abs(doc['age'].value - 30)`, everything works.